# Get the current active modal dialog in java

Tags: java, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a small dialog that is independent from the rest of the whole project. There are several threads that can call this dialog.

The problem is a modal JDialog that shows the progress of the current task. My dialog will be opened behind the progress dialog. There is no possibility to get this dialog.

Is it possible to get the current active dialog so that I can use them as the parent of my new dialog?

Comment: "There are several threads that can call this dialog." - Surely only the Event Dispatch Thread should be invoking this dialog (assuming you're using Swing)?

Comment: The progress dialog works with the SwingWorker. The problem is that the first call may be from the task of the SwingWorker and a second from another position (undefinable, because the created dialog is to accept SSL certificates and can happen each time a SSL connection is established.)

But you're right, I had to refactor some of the code to allow the tasks to get the progress dialog etc. I think now I got a working version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points:

You state that several threads can potentially call this dialog, whereas for a Swing application you should ensure that the Event Dispatch Thread is the only thread that launches this dialog.

If you follow this constraint it is more likely that you'll have a reference to the already displayed progress dialog and will therefore be able to use it as the dialog parent.

It sounds like you potentially need to rearchitect your application.  Typically you might invoke a SwingWorker to perform the background task, which would "publish" progress back onto the Swing thread, which would then update the progress dialog.

Another tip: You can use the `toFront()` method on `Window` to bring a dialog to the front of the screen, although this doesn't seem to be the crux of your problem.